# writeObject() and readObject() are not called during serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a Test class, shown below:

```
package examples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class Test implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2174245110865129519L;

  private transient int num = 5;

  /**
   * Write object (Serialization).
   */
  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Write Test!");
    // Save state.
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    // Save sum.
    out.writeObject(num);
  }

  /**
   * Read object (Deserialization).
   */
  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Read Test!");
    // Restore state.
    in.defaultReadObject();
    // Restore num.
    num = (int) in.readObject();
  }

}
```

Now the problem is that when I want to serialize a Test object as a JSON file for example with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) like this:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(new Test());
```

... writeObject() and readObject() are not called at all, and I get a JSON file with an empty object. I use Java 8.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writeObject` and `readObject` methods will be called on Java Serialization, which is converting data of the current object into bytes and writing these bytes into an stream, or reading the bytes from a stream and creating an object from there. What you're doing there is JSON serialization, which **is not** Java serialization, so `writeObject` and `readObject` methods won't be used at all (unless the JSON encoder/decoder establishes that it wil use them). If you need to customize the serialization/deserialization of JSON using Gson, you may check this: http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-custom-serializer-deserializer.jsp (not a Gson user, so if there's anyone else who knows how this can be achieved, feel free to edit this post to improve it)

Also, you're getting an empty result because there aren't fields to serialize in your `Test` class. Note that `num` cannot be serialized by Gson because it's marked as `transient`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know the transient "modifier", that was just an example to give some logic to the example code.